# Angularjs's controller dependancy with requirejs?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am using angular js with require js to make a single page template.
Everything is working accept one thing. When I am trying to define controller name in $routeProvider, it shows an error:

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=SignIn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

I separate the files like that:

```
rootfolder
    js
      -require.js
      -angular.min.js
      -angular-route.js
      -main.js
      -app.js
      -signin.js
      -signup.js

    index.php
    sign_in.php
    sign_up.php
```

My code:

Main.js

```
 require.config({
        baseUrl: "./js",
        paths: {
            'angular': 'angular.min',
            'angularRoute': 'angular-route'
        },
        shim: { 
            'angular' : { exports : 'angular' },
            'angularRoute' : { deps : ['angular'] }
        },
        deps: ['app']
    });
```

App.js

```
  define(['angular','angularRoute'], function (angularRoute) {
        var app = angular.module('webapp', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(['$routeProvider',
                            function($routeProvider) {
                                $routeProvider.
                                  when('/signin', {
                                    templateUrl: 'sign_in.php',
                                    controller: 'SignIn'
                                  }).
                                  when('/signup', {
                                    templateUrl: 'sign_up.php',
                                    controller: 'SignUp'
                                  }).
                                  otherwise({
                                    redirectTo: '/signin'
                                  });
                              }
          ]);
        return app;
    });
```

controller - signin.js

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller('SignIn', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Sign in page"; 
    });

});
```

controller - signup.js

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller('SignUp', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Sign up page"; 
    }); 
});
```

When I define controller: 'SignIn' or controller: 'SignUp' in $routeProvider  it shows an error otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Where do you require SignIn and SignUp? So far I cannot see where you include them... `controller: 'SignIn'` will not trigger any requirejs to run...

Comment: In app.js when defining controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make requirejs include `signin.js` and `signup.js`, too. The code you have in App.js does not trigger any requirejs calls to load these two files.

```
when('/signin', {
    templateUrl: 'sign_in.php',
    controller: 'SignIn'
})
```

only tells AngularJS to try and instantiate the controller called 'SignIn' once you navigate to /signin. However, this will *not* result in the loading of the signin.js file.

Make sure to have your outer most module to depend on `signin` and `signup`, too.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I defined module in controller                              define(['signin'], function (signin) {
 var signIn = angular.module('signin',[]);
    signIn.controller('ctrlSignIn', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Sign in page"; 
    });
 return signIn;
});                                                                                                            and defined the dependency in app.js like this define(['angular','angularRoute','signin','signup'], function (angularRoute,signin,signup) {
 var app = angular.module('webapp', ['ngRoute','signin','signup']); .